# Custom class for query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have the following query in my Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int Id)
{
    var People = from a in db.Person
                 select a;

    var Data = from a in db.Member
               where a.Person.PersonId.Equals(Id)
               select new CustomObject
               {
                   ProjectId = a.Project.ProjectId,
                   ProjectName = a.Project.Name,
                   ProjectCustomer = a.Project.Customer,

                   ProjectTechProfile = a.Project.TechProfile.Select(x => new
                   {
                       x.TechId,
                       x.Name,
                       x.Elements
                   }),

                   MemberId = a.MemberId,
                   MemberRole = a.Role,
                   MemberStart = a.Start,
                   MemberEnd = a.End
               };
```

And I'm making a custom class for my Data query, but I don't know how to set the property of TechProfile

Right now I have this in my custom class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyProject.Models
{
public class CustomObject
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCustomer { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TechProfile> ProjectTechProfile { get; set; }

    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public string MemberRole { get; set; }
    public short? MemberStart { get; set; }
    public short? MemberEnd { get; set; }
}
}
```

But the part with

```
public IEnumerable<TechProfile> ProjectTechProfile { get; set; }
```

Doesn't work, so do I need to specify TechId, Name and Elements? If so, how?

**UPDATE**

TechProfile class

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class TechProfile
{
    public int TechId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Elements { get; set; }
    public int ProjectProjectId { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: `ProjectTechProfile = a.Project.TechProfile.Select(x => new TekniskProfil() { TechId = x.TechId, ...etc }),`

Comment: Can you show how TechProfile class looks like?

Comment: Hi, what is **`a.Project.TechProfile`** ? is it a list/collection of TechProfile?

Answer (score 0):

```
    ...                   
    ProjectTechProfile = a.Project.TechProfile.Select(x => new TechProfile()
                       {
                           TechId = x.TechId,
                           Name = x.Name,
                           Elements = x.Elements
                       },
    ...
```

Comment: I just want those 3 specific items from my TechProfile, and when I try to use new TechProfile() I get the error Cannot initialize type MyProject.Models.TechProfile with a collection initializer because it does not implement System.Collections.IEnumerable